# tableViewCellにaddSubviewしたcollectionViewをタップした場合、tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)が呼ばれない。

Tags: swift, xcode

tableViewCellにaddSubviewしたcollectionViewをタップした時、

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

が呼ばれないのですが、
どのようにすれば、呼ばれますか？

Comment: `UICollectionView`には`UICollectionViewDelegate`と`UICollectionnViewDatasource`の２つのプロトコルを持っているので、CollectionViewのインスタンスがタップされたときには
`UICollectionViewDelegate`の`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`が呼ばれると思いますが、こちらは実装していますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！はい、collectionViewのdidSelectItem...の方は呼ばれます。なので、このメソッドの中でtableViewCellのタップを検知して処理もできるのですが、同時にtableViewの方のdidSelectメソッドが呼ばれるなら、tableViewCellを簡単に取得できたりシンプルになるのではと思っています。なのでcollectionViewのタップを透過してtableViewの方のdelegateメソッドも呼ばれるようにする方法はないかと思っています。

Comment: `addSubview`するviewを`UICollectionView`のサブクラスにして、そのサブクラスで`acceptsFirstResponder`をオーバーライドし、NOを返すようにするとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: `class DropsCollectionView: UICollectionView {
  
    func acceptsFi‌​rstResponder() -> Bool {
        return false
    }}`

としましたが、あいにく反応変わらずです。

Comment: う〜ん、レスポンダーにならなければSuperViewのタップアクションが呼ばれると思ったんですが、お役に立てず申し訳ありません

Comment: いえいえ、ありがとうございます！